# flatness and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Given: domains $A$ and $B$ such that $A\subseteq B$ and such that their fraction fields are equal. Also $A$ is a unique factorization domain and if $a \in A$ is a unit in $B$, it is a unit in $A$. I want to show that if $A \subseteq B$ is flat then $B=A$. I think I need to use the fact that every element in $B$ can be written as $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$ with $a_1,a_2 \in A$. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Something is flat as a module (or a module morphism). But $A$ is not, in general, a module over $B$. The only way I can attribute a meaning to “$A\subseteq B$ is flat” is that $B$ is flat as an $A$-module.

Comment: @egreg: This is very common terminology.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Not that $A$ is flat.

Comment: Oh, you refered to an older version of the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The assumption $A \cap B^* = A^*$ implies that $\mathfrak{p}B \neq B$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$, i.e. that $B$ is faithfully flat over $A$. Now use [SE/482908](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482908/).

Comment: Why $\mathfrak pB\neq B$ and why this is enough to conclude that $B$ is f.f. over $A$?

Comment: Due to the lack of any explanation I consider this answer as being far from complete (possible wrong) and I give it a -1.